# Recycler view adapter not reflecting changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a recycler view adapter set up in my MainActivity. That adapter is hooked up to an arraylist of a custom object I made called group.

```
public static RecyclerView.Adapter groupsListAdapter;
public ArrayList<Group> myGroups;
```

//inside onCreate of Main Activity

```
groupsListAdapter = new MyAdapter(myGroups);
```

In a different Activity, I am updating the contents of this arraylist, first by passing it through the intent.

```
Intent groupCreationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewGroupActivity.class);
        groupCreationIntent.putExtra("groupsList",myGroups);
        startActivity(groupCreationIntent);
```

And then updating it in the other activity.

```
private ArrayList<Group> groups;
```

//in oncreate method of other activity

```
groups = (ArrayList<Group>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("groupsList");
```

When going back to the previous activity (the second activity is used for entering some information and syncing it with my database) I run this code.

```
groups.add(myGroup);
MainActivity.groupsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
finish();
```

The problem is that the list adapter is not reflecting the changes, nothing is appearing in my list once i return to the main activity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If an arraylist is getting populated, then it would be better if you do the last part of notifydataset change on the main activity after getting the results.

Comment: have you checked other posts about notifydatasetchange() not reflecting changes?

Answer (score 1):

```java
class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

  private List<Group> items;

  public MyAdapter(List<Group> items) {
    this.items = items;
  }

  // .. your implementation

  // add and call this
  public void add(Group item) {
    this.items.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
  }
}
```

it's not related with your question, you should not use static field for Activity-to-Activity communication.